# Assign Roles to Users during Registration - Play-authenticate with deadbolt

Tags: playframework-2.0, play-authenticate, deadbolt-2

I have created 2 custom roles for my project. I want to assign a Role to the users during the registration process. How can I assign a role by default to the user during the registration.

Also, how can I create 2 registration forms, if I have 2 different roles. I need 2 types of registrations for different types of roles.

Answer (score 1):

In the `save` method of your `UserServicePlugin` implementation, you can add roles when you create the user.  For example, assuming you have a model called `User` that implements Deadbolt's `Subject` interface,

```
@Override
public Object save(final AuthUser authUser)
{
    final boolean isExistingUser = User.existsByAuthUserIdentity(authUser);
    Long id = null;
    if (!isExistingUser)
    {
        User user = User.create(authUser);
        id = user.id;

        user.giveRole("some role name");
    }
    return id;
}
```

The `giveRole` method of is something like this.

```
public void giveRole(String roleName)
{
    SecurityRole role = SecurityRole.findByRoleName(roleName);
    if (!roles.contains(role))
    {
        roles = new ArrayList<>(roles);
        roles.add(role);
        update();
        Ebean.saveAssociation(this, "roles");
    }
}
```

This assumes you're using Ebean and Java, but the mechanics are the same if you're using Scala or a different database tool.

For having different roles assigned on user creation, move the bit where you assign roles out of the `save` method and into (for example) the controller methods through which these registrations come.

Comment: Please am using Play-authenticate library embedded with deadbolt. I can create roles by adding roles in DataInitializer.java. But i dont know how to create separate signup for my manager role and admin role.                                           if (SecurityRole.find.findRowCount() == 0) {
            for (final String roleName : Arrays
                    .asList(controllers.Application.ADMIN_ROLE)) {
                final SecurityRole role = new SecurityRole();
                role.roleName = roleName;
                role.save();
            }
        }